# enum not working, expected declaration

Tags: swift, enumeration

I'm new to swift and am trying to use `enumeration`:

```
    enum students : String {
        case Joseph = "Joseph", Matt = "Matt", Cody = "Cody", Rick = "Rick"

        static let allValues = [Joseph, Matt, Cody, Rick]

        for Joseph in students.allValues{
        studentPic.image = UIImage(named: "joseph.gif")
        studentLabel.alpha = 1
        studentLabel.text = "Joseph is an A+ student"
        }
        for Matt in students.allValues{
        studentPic.image = UIImage(named: "matt.gif")
        studentLabel.alpha = 1
        studentLabel.text = "Matt is a B+ student"
        }
        for Cody in students.allValues{
        studentPic.image = UIImage(named: "cody.gif")
        studentLabel.alpha = 1
        studentLabel.text = "Cody is a C+ student"
        }
        for Rick in students.allValues{
        studentPic.image = UIImage(named: "rick.gif")
        studentLabel.alpha = 1
        studentLabel.text = "Rick is a D+ student"
        }

    }
```

I get "`Expected declaration`" for the first line :

```
for Joseph in students.allValues
```

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've put arbitrary code in the body of an `enum` - that won't work.  You need either func declarations or variable declarations (although perhaps not even in a `enum` if they are stored properties).  Fix your code with:

```
  enum students : String {
    case Joseph = "Joseph", Matt = "Matt", Cody = "Cody", Rick = "Rick"

    static let allValues = [Joseph, Matt, Cody, Rick]

    func doSomething () {
      for Joseph in students.allValues{
        studentPic.image = UIImage(named: "joseph.gif")
        studentLabel.alpha = 1
        studentLabel.text = "Joseph is an A+ student"
      }
      // ...
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

I came across the same issue while migrating existing objC code to swift.

What I had to do to fix it was to import the class which contains enums (in my case `Constants.h ) to bridging header.

Hope it helps someone.